# iOS Google maps dynamically update/remove programmatically created markers

Tags: ios, google-maps, dynamic, marker, programmatically-created

I am stuck with some lack of xcode / iOS programming knowledge.

I have created a track in google maps for iOS, and programmatically created markers along this track. What I would like to do is update these markers with actual information in the .title / .snippet (ie. distance to go, time to go etc) or remove them all together. 
But when you create markers in a loop there is no way of keeping track of them.
since the amount of markers can vary from 2 to 50 it would be strange in my opinion to create 50 different variables for each marker, I guess there must be another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can keeping track of created markers.
Each GMSMarker has property userData. You can add some string tag or other custom object to identify this marker.

e.g.
    `marker.userData = @{@"key" : @"some tag"};`

Comment: userData is a dictionary :)